# Launching flows in a SalesForce Community site

Tags: portal

I'm relatively new to Salesforce and I'm looking to create a button to launch a flow from a record list view page on an Experience/Community site.  The flow and button are created, and they work well for internal users in regular screens, but when I launch the flow from the Community site or log in as a Community user the flow doesn't launch.  No errors, they just don't do anything.  I believe I have correctly configured the "Run Flows" permission for my community users' Profile.

I've tried creating the flow as both a Screen Flow and an AutoTriggered flow....the flow basically performs some background tasks like record creation that does not require any user input.

What am I missing?  Been banging my head for days, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permission issue. Make sure that the community user has the correct permissions to use that specific flow. You should try debugging the flow as that user, it should give you more information as to what the issue could be. However it does sound like a permission issue since the flow isn't launching as that specific profile.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Matthew!  Something I left out in my original post was that even if I sign in as a regular internal user -- I can trigger the flow OK from a regular record listing screen.....but not in the Experience site.